# PCI Express x1 in a PCI Slot

Tags: compatibility, pci-express

Will this work? I found a cheap serial port card I need for a POS receipt printer but I'm not sure if the computer has a PCI Express x1 slot.

For sure it has a PCI slot though so I'm wondering if I can pop it in

Answer (score 5):

[image]

No, they have different sized slots, and their buses differ.

The image used in this answer is taken from ( http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/PCIExpress.jpg ), and has been modified to include text and indication circles in red. It is licensed under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: Oh Okay, what about a pci express x1 in pci express x16?

Comment: Have you done any reading on PCI-express?

Comment: I prefer to go straight to the pros

Comment: @Scandalist Technically yes you can put a x1 in an x16 slot, the extra lanes just won't be used. However in real life, on some computers it doesn't work because the manufacterer has made alterations. ( http://superuser.com/questions/89222/will-a-regular-pci-express-card-work-in-a-pci-express-x16-graphics-peg-slot?rq=1 )

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb tends to be you can put a 'smaller' PCIe card into a larger slot - so a x1 will fit in an x16.

If you're trying to put in an pci e x1  card into a pci slot, adaptors exist - these use chips that were originally meant for using GPUs designed for pci-e on PCI. Most systems should have at least one x1 card slot, unless this is something like mini ITX

*However* many modern systems do still have serial port headers. Its worth checking if you have one, getting a suitable adaptor and using that instead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The system does have a serial port but they have two receipt printers

Answer (score 0):

You can place a PCIe 1x card into any available PCIe slot and it will work -- even if the slot is longer than the card.

You can NOT plug it into the PCI slot however.

Comment: Not entirely true. From my experience today, you **can** use a PCI-E card on a PCI slot. However, don't expect it to have good results. My accidental insertion of a PCI-E NIC into a PCI slot worked until I really strained it. The system would become inaccessible until transfers ceased.

Comment: @TylerMontney; I don't think you understand the difference between PCI and PCIe.  PCI slots disappeared from most PC motherboards a decade ago.  They are both physically and electrically incompatible with PCIe.  If you ever did manage to get a PCIe card to physically fit in a PCI slot (which would involve removing the bracket and forcing it in backwards), it wouldn't work in the best case scenario, and might fry the card in the worst case scenario.

Comment: I double checked the motherboard specs, it is listed as a PCI slot. It is also the only slot not populated, and I have no issues with the other slots. Since I was using a PCI-E x1, it fit fine. I still have my A+ cert from nearly a decade ago. I'd agree, like everyone else, that PCI-E is incompatible with PCI. However, unless there's another PCI-E slot I'm unaware of, I can't explain why it "functioned". I'm stating that it did, and hoping someone can explain why.

Comment: @TylerMontney; You sure it wasn’t a [PCI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X) slot? They were once common on server boards but some high-end desktop boards had them too. Most PCI-X slots will accept a regular PCI card and vice versa.

Comment: Nope. Just looked it up and the slot isn't nearly that long. Slot also has one notch, PCI-X has two. Board is consumer, mid-range at best.