# PCIe card and x8/x16 lanes

Tags: pci

I have a card that says it is PCIe x8 card (which means 8 lanes, if I'm not mistaken). Can it be physically plugged in a slot x16? Will it work, assuming drivers/OS support ?

The motherboard is ASUS P5Q-EM (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QEM/), it supports PCIe v2.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PCI-Express specifications, PCI-Express cards can be plugged into slots with more lanes than necessary without physical issues, the cards and slots are designed that way. (In some motherboards you can also plug in cards into slots with fewer lanes, but that isn't always the case.)

If your card isn't a graphics card though you may run into issues; some only support graphics cards (called PEG cards, for PCI Express Graphics), especially older boards.

See [Will a regular PCI Express card work in a "PCI Express x16 Graphics (PEG)" slot?](https://superuser.com/questions/89222/will-a-regular-pci-express-card-work-in-a-pci-express-x16-graphics-peg-slot) for more information.

Comment: The question you link to says the opposite of what you claim: PCIe is PCIe, and there is nothing special about the PEG slot or graphics cards, so you can plug anything in there and it will work.  The one thing that can be a problem on bad boards is that they disable the integrated graphics if you plug anything into the PEG slot, but the device there still works.

Comment: Just because the PCIe standard specifies how slots should work doesn't mean motherboard manufacturers actually comply in all cases. You're correct this is how it *should* be, but I've personally worked on server motherboards where not all PCI Express slots behaved the same.

Comment: @psusi The accepted answer adds the "modern motherboards" caveat. I've seen motherboards which fail to boot with a non-PEG card in the PEG slot, others which never initialise any non-PEG card there.

Comment: Yes, and the "non modern motherboards" just disable the on board graphics regardless of whether the card is a GPU or not.  The device in the slot still works.